# The application "2x RDP" Connection Error

Tags: wine, rdp

I have recently switched to Ubuntu from Windows. I am using 12.10 currently. Will move to 14.04 soon. I have managed to make everything work on Ubuntu except an application I use at work. Its called 2x RDP. I have installed its Linux version, and ran the exe using Wine but they both give me errors. Everybody else is using the app from Windows but I can't use it from Ubuntu. Can anyone help me troubleshoot the problem?

I am posting the errors I get. It was working fine when I was on Windows.

---

When running through Wine:

```
2X RDP - 202.59.74.233

Code [02/00000006]
The client could not establish a connection to the remote computer.

The most likely causes for this error are:
1) The servers are too busy to service your request.
2) The machine is not part of the farm.
```

---

When running through Debian Installation:

```
2X Cllent
The specified remote 2X Connection could not be found.
Verify that you have typed the correct computer name or IP address.
and then try to connect again.
```

---

Comment: Someone pl help. I need this to work for my office. Its important that this thing works

Comment: The problem has now solved as my company's IT guys have changed the server of 2x and the 2x app from the Software Center is now working. Otherwise I had install MicroXP on a VirtualBox and it was working from there also